# Populating a Collection Property in XAML: Item DataContext is null

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have a control that has an `ObservableCollection` of one or more key-value pairs. That can be provided as a ready-made `ObservableCollection` by the ViewModel bound as usual (`Keys={Binding KeyCollection}` -- which works perfectly), but I'd like to be able to define it in XAML as well:

```
<foo:KeyControl>
    <foo:KeyItem Key="ID" Value="{Binding ID}" />
    <foo:KeyItem Key="HatSize" Value="{Binding HatSize}" />
</foo:KeyControl>
```

`KeyItem` is derived from `FrameworkElement`, and the properties `Key` and `Value` are dependency properties. I've got a `ContentPropertyAttribute` on `KeyControl`, and that's working fine: The correct collection property is populated, and the `Key` properties (the ones with literal values, not bindings) are initialized as in the XAML.

The trouble is that the bindings for the `Value` properties don't work. They always assign null to the property. I think that's because the `KeyItem` instances have a null `DataContext`.

Also, RelativeSource FindAncestor thinks there aren't any ancestors to find:

```
<foo:KeyItem Type="ID" 
    Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.ID, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=foo:MyView}, 
    diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
```

When new `KeyItem` instances are added to the `ObservableCollection`, I've tried setting their DataContext to be that of the control, but the control's DataContext is always null at that point (?!) if they're defined in XAML.

What am I missing?

UPDATE

The content of the answer was in [a linked article](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) by Thomas Levesque, so in case that goes offline, here's the fix: You create a proxy as a resource. Where you define the resource, the control's DataContext is in scope. In the bindings on the collection item properties, you can get to the resource.

C#:

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    #region Overrides of Freezable

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    #endregion

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables 
    // animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), 
            typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

XAML:

```
<foo:KeyControl>
    <foo:KeyControl.Resources>
        <foo:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
    </foo:KeyControl.Resources>

    <foo:KeyItem Key="ID" Value="{Binding Data.ID, 
        Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
    <foo:KeyItem Key="HatSize" Value="{Binding Data.HatSize, 
        Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
</foo:KeyControl>
```

Bit of a kludge, but it works. I think I may just stick with binding the collection from the ViewModels, though.

For search purposes, I was getting the "Framework mentor not found" error on this when the `DataContexts` were null.

Comment: *What am I missing?*... apparently quite a lot. If I were you, I'd have a good, *long* read of the [Data Binding Overview‎](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN before you continue.

Comment: Wow, really? No, it's not at all that *I* don't have a clue... it's more a case that *you* have so much wrong with *your* idea and code that I don't have the time or patience to help you. You're *clearly* missing the most basic WPF information, so I kindly provided you with a very useful link to MSDN instead. And for that, you insult me? I'm really surprised that anyone with over 1000 reputation points would act in such an immature way. Good luck with your problem.

Comment: @Sheridan It's not helpful to demand that somebody guess what you think is wrong with his question, and if you really feel the need to be that offensive about it, you're not likely to get a very patient reply.

Comment: Wow, so you're still carrying on? Let's get things into perspective, shall we? What was so horrendous about my comment that made you fly into such a rage that you felt that it was ok to add your rude and abusive comments (that have now been deleted)? The fact that I said that I thought that you were missing *quite a lot*? Was that it? Really? It's a real shame that you had such an adverse reaction to such a minor comment. As for demanding... please show me how exactly I demanded anything. If you'll just step down off your high horse for a moment, perhaps we could all get along better?

Comment: @Sheridan You keep insisting that there's something wrong with the question and railing about how ignorant I am, but you refuse to provide any specifics about any of it. Since you're typing it all in the comment box here, I can only imagine that you mean for me to guess what your mysterious point is. Why else bother? You can run sobbing to the mods to delete this comment too, but it won't make you feel any better than it did last time. Please note that my question has been answered, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with the datacontext not inheriting and I solved my problem using the proxy technique described here 
http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/

Hope this helps